# How to import Case-Sensitive data from Oracle to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, migration, case-sensitive

I am trying to import data from Oracle into SQL Server using SSIS.

The problem is I have a PK of datatype `VARCHAR2(200)` in one of the tables having case-sensitive data in Oracle DB. Hence, the SSIS, while importing the data, is throwing

> *Violation of PK, cannot insert duplicate value in PK*

How should I work around this? Any solution for this EXCEPT accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371234/problem-with-database-collation-change-sql-server-2008) because it's not feasible for me to drop and create the DB for enabling case-sensitive data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to Recreate database. You just need to set Case Sensitive column.

Open in Design mode Table, choose your column and push Collation row.

[image: Table design mode]

Just check "Case Sensitive" checkbox, push OK and Save Table. now It will be OK.

[image: Collation editing]

Comment: Thanks, did't know that option ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a new column, set its collation to case sensitive one, reload the records and then rename them accordingly:

```
SELECT 1 AS TEST INTO #TT
ALTER TABLE #TT ADD new_pk_case_sensitive VARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```