# Changing the collation of a SQL Server 2012 database

Tags: sql-server, collation

**Alter Collation**

I need to change the collation of one of our databases on a particular server from `Latin1_General_CI_AS` to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` so that it matches the rest of our databases.

[image: Alter Collation Dialog - SQL Server 2012 R2]

**The Problem**

However, when I attempt to do this, I get the following error:

> ALTER DATABASE failed. The default collation of database 'XxxxxXxxxxx' cannot be set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5075)

**My Research**

My googling on the topic has revealed a number of articles which indicate that I need to export all the data, drop the database, re-create it with the correct collation, then re-import the data.

For example: [Problem with database collation change (SQL Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371234/problem-with-database-collation-change-sql-server-2008)

Obviously this is a significant task, especially since primary-foreign key relationships must be preserved, and our database is quite large (over ten million data rows).

**My Question**

Is there a way to change the collation of an existing SQL Server 2012 database which does not require exporting and re-importing all the data?

Alternatively, is there some tool or script(s) which can automate this process in a reliable manner?

Comment: Mark, I know it has been almost 4 years ;-), but I just updated my answer with additional info that might be of interest if you ever face this issue again. Please see the **UPDATE** section at the bottom.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, to be fair, I have found 1 or 2 unofficial scripts that attempt to drop dependencies, alter collation, and then re-create the dependencies. Haven't tried them so I don't know if they are reliable or not. I can post the links if you are interested. The benefit would be, if they actually work, is that they would do a single DB instead of the entire Instance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The following works for me on SQL Server 2012:

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI;
```

The accepted answer in the linked question is not entirely correct, at least not for SQL Server 2012. It says:

> Ahh, this is one of the worst problems in SQL Server: you cannot change the collation once an object is created (this is true both for tables and databases...).

But I was just able to change the default collation and I have tables that are populated.  The MSDN page for [ALTER DATABASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174269(v=sql.110).aspx) states in the "Remarks" section, under "Changing the Database Collation":

> Before you apply a different collation to a database, make sure that the following conditions are in place:
>
> 1. You are the only one currently using the database.
> 2. No schema-bound object depends on the collation of the database.
>
>    If the following objects, which depend on the database collation, exist in the database, the ALTER DATABASE *database_name* COLLATE statement will fail. SQL Server will return an error message for each object blocking the ALTER action:
>
>    - User-defined functions and views created with SCHEMABINDING.
>    - Computed columns.
>    - CHECK constraints.
>    - Table-valued functions that return tables with character columns with collations inherited from the default database collation.

So, I would suggest making sure that the database is in Single-User mode, and that if you have any of those four items, that you:

- drop them
- change the collation
- and then re-add them

**BUT,** at that point all that has been changed is the Database's default Collation. The Collation of any existing columns in user tables (i.e. non-system tables) will still have the original Collation. If you want existing string columns -- `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, and the deprecated `TEXT` and `NTEXT` -- to take on the new Collation, you need to change each of those columns individually. And, if there are any indexes defined on those columns, then those indexes will need to be dropped first (disabling is not enough) and created again after the `ALTER COLUMN` (other dependencies that would prevent the `ALTER COLUMN` would have already been dropped in order to get the `ALTER DATABASE` to work). The example below illustrates this behavior:

**Test Setup**

```
USE [tempdb];
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE dbo.ChangeCollationParent
(
  [ChangeCollationParentID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
                    CONSTRAINT [PK_ChangeCollationParent]  PRIMARY KEY,
  ExtendedASCIIString VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
  UnicodeString NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ChangeCollationChild
(
  [ChangeCollationChildID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
                    CONSTRAINT [PK_ChangeCollationChild]  PRIMARY KEY,
  [ChangeCollationParentID] INT NULL
                    CONSTRAINT [FK_ChangeCollationChild_ChangeCollationParent] FOREIGN KEY
                         REFERENCES dbo.ChangeCollationParent([ChangeCollationParentID]),
  ExtendedASCIIString VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
  UnicodeString NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeCollationParent ([ExtendedASCIIString], [UnicodeString])
VALUES ('test1' + CHAR(200), N'test1' + NCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeCollationParent ([ExtendedASCIIString], [UnicodeString])
VALUES ('test2' + CHAR(170), N'test2' + NCHAR(170));


INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeCollationChild
         ([ChangeCollationParentID], [ExtendedASCIIString], [UnicodeString])
VALUES (1, 'testA ' + CHAR(200), N'testA ' + NCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeCollationChild
         ([ChangeCollationParentID], [ExtendedASCIIString], [UnicodeString])
VALUES (1, 'testB ' + CHAR(170), N'testB ' + NCHAR(170));

SELECT * FROM dbo.ChangeCollationParent;
SELECT * FROM dbo.ChangeCollationChild;
```

**Test 1: Change column Collation with no dependencies**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChangeCollationParent
  ALTER COLUMN [ExtendedASCIIString] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChangeCollationParent
  ALTER COLUMN [UnicodeString] NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NULL;

ALTER TABLE dbo.ChangeCollationChild
  ALTER COLUMN [ExtendedASCIIString] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChangeCollationChild
  ALTER COLUMN [UnicodeString] NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NULL;

SELECT * FROM dbo.ChangeCollationParent;
SELECT * FROM dbo.ChangeCollationChild;
```

The `ALTER COLUMN` statements above complete successfully.

**Test 2: Change column Collation with dependencies**

```
-- First, create an index:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ChangeCollationParent_ExtendedASCIIString]
  ON dbo.ChangeCollationParent ([ExtendedASCIIString] ASC);

-- Next, change the Collation back to the original setting:
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChangeCollationParent
  ALTER COLUMN [ExtendedASCIIString] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL;
```

This time, the `ALTER COLUMN` statement received the following error:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
>   The index 'IX_ChangeCollationParent_ExtendedASCIIString' is dependent on column 'ExtendedASCIIString'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 60
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ExtendedASCIIString failed because one or more objects access this column.

**ALSO,** please be aware that the Collation of some string columns in database-scoped system catalog views (e.g. `sys.objects`, `sys.columns`, `sys.indexes`, etc) will change to the new Collation. If your code has JOINs to any of these string columns (i.e. `name`), then you might start getting Collation mismatch errors until you change the Collation on the joining columns in your user tables.

**UPDATE:**

If changing the Collation for the entire Instance is the desire, or an option, then there is an easier method that bypasses all of these restrictions. It is undocumented and hence unsupported (so if it doesn't work, Microsoft isn't going to help). However, it changes the Collation at all levels: Instance, all Database's, and all string columns in all User Tables. It does this, and avoids all of the typical restrictions, by simply updating the meta-data of the tables, etc to have the new Collation. It then drops and recreates all indexes that have string columns. There are also a few nuances to this method that might have impact, but are fixable. This method is the `-q` command-line switch of `sqlservr.exe`. I have documented all of the behaviors, including listing all of the potentially affected areas by doing such a wide-sweeping Collation change, in the following post:

[Changing the Collation of the Instance, the Databases, and All Columns in All User Databases: What Could Possibly Go Wrong?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/06/11/changing-the-collation-of-the-instance-and-all-columns-across-all-user-databases-what-could-possibly-go-wrong/)

Comment: This method does not work if anything in the database uses any of the columns in question. For instance, if you have an SP that has something like "WHERE x=y" and x and y are varchars, you cannot change the collation because of issue (2). So basically it works for databases you don't actually care about, and fails for anything real-world.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz regarding "_if you have an SP that has something like "WHERE x=y" and x and y are varchars, you cannot change the collation because of issue (2)_": have you tried this and found that it did not work, or are you going based on what the documentation that I quoted says? Because I have tried it and it does indeed work. You are misreading point #2. It has nothing to do with stored procs, and (N)VARCHAR columns have a defined Collation. It is string literals, parameters, and some columns in system catalog tables that are affected as they are controlled by the db default collation.

Comment: I tried it today, that's how I came across this thread, trying to solve exactly that. There are a number of strong depandances when you have views, SPs or similar that have any sort of comparison between text columns, and the only solution is to drop them all and recreate them. I have tried a few solutions from various sources, but they all fail for one reason or another.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz What did you try, and what error did you get? I tried your situation and it works just fine. In my SP, only the IF condition was affected in terms of changing behavior because it was comparing a param to a string literal, and that behavior change was expected. Yes, Views created using `WITH SCHEMABINDING` will be an issue, as stated in that documentation. Views selecting from database-level system tables would likely need to have `sp_refreshview` called on them to regenerate the result set schema. But there are no inherent issues with Stored Procedures.

Comment: Can't say for sure, I got about 500 errors and most of them were on SPs. I don't have a smaller set I could try.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Well, the errors might occur within the SP, but not because of the SP itself. I'm sure it was a commonly-used subset of objects that caused most / all of those errors.

Comment: I'm sure that is the case, but I just tried this on all 8 DBs in my server, just for fun, and it failed on all of them. This method appears to work for a tiny subset of DBs (as the many, many threads on this topic note). So if it works for you, most excellent, keep using it, but don't expect it to work even most of the time.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I don't see your point. You seem to be using overly broad definitions of "tried this" and "doesn't work". Neither I nor the documentation states that this will always work without errors. It specifically states what items will cause the errors, and those just need to be dropped and recreated. If you did not identifying those objects, and drop them, so that you could run the command and then recreate them, then you did _not_ try this. And for objects that are schema-bound, you likely just need to ALTER to remove the schema binding, then alter back after the Collation change.

Comment: While this will change the database's default collation, it won't update any already existing columns. You can update them in-place though, one at a time with the alter column.. command. As with other objects mentioned above, you may need to drop & recreate indexes etc. It's no picnic anyway you do it, unfortunately.

Comment: @GarethLyons True, I was only really addressing the primary issue of whether or not `ALTER DATABASE` can work once tables are added (as the O.P. had gotten an error on it and thought that it was not possible at all). But, I do see how the absence of info pertaining to the existing columns potentially left things a bit misleading. So, I have updated my answer with that info and even some example code. Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Please see the **UPDATE** section I just added to the bottom of my answer, and the associated link. It is a method that handles gets passed most / all of those errors on dependent objects. Undocumented, but quite nifty.

Comment: @GarethLyons Please see the **UPDATE** section I just added to the bottom of my answer, and the associated link. It is a method that handles changing all existing columns in all User Tables. It also bypasses errors that would normally happen if you had indexes / constraints / etc referencing those columns. Undocumented, but quite nifty.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else stumbling to this problem, the solution is to set DB in single_user mode before change the collation and then set again the multi_user mode after it.
Make sure to not close the connection before setting the multi_user mode!

```
/* block all other users from connecting to the db */
ALTER DATABASE YorDbName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 

/* modify your db collate */
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI;

/* allow again all other users to connect to the db */
ALTER DATABASE YorDbName SET MULTI_USER;
```