# How to change the collation in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, collation

Our database has a collation of `SQL Latin General CI_AS`, we need to change it to `SQL Latin General CS_AS`.

Is there a way to change the collation without rebuilding the database?

Maybe can we change the collation for specific tables?

Comment: welcome to SO, look at https://www.sanssql.com/2013/10/change-sql-server-collation-without.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the collation of a SQL Server 2012 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132895/changing-the-collation-of-a-sql-server-2012-database)